# Can I combine try catch blocks?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> GetNextBase36(string partitionKey, string rowKey, ref string seq)
    {
        Sequence sequence;
        try {
            sequence = _sequenceRepository.Get(u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey & u.RowKey == rowKey);
        } catch {
            _errors.Add("", "Database error: Get sequence failed");
        }
        try {
            sequence.Value = Base36.Encode(Base36.Decode(sequence.Value) + 1);
            _sequenceRepository.AddOrUpdate(sequence);
            seq = sequence.Value;
        } catch {
            _errors.Add("", "Database error: Updating sequence failed");
        }
        return _errors;
    }
```

It works but it seems overkill to have each database access surrounded by a try catch block. Is there some way I could simplify this? Is there any beter approach?

Updated code based on help / advice:

```
    public IDictionary<string, string> GetNextBase36(string partitionKey, string rowKey, ref string seq)
    {
        Sequence sequence;
        string catchMsg = string.Empty;
        try {
            catchMsg = "Database error: Get sequence failed"
            sequence = _sequenceRepository.Get(u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey & u.RowKey == rowKey);
            sequence.Value = Base36.Encode(Base36.Decode(sequence.Value) + 1);
            catchMsg = "Database error: Updating sequence failed"
            _sequenceRepository.AddOrUpdate(sequence);
            seq = sequence.Value;
        } catch {
            _errors.Add("", catchMsg);
        }
        return _errors;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not liking what I'm seeing there.

Comment: Your code is broken, if the first dbaccess throws, it will swallow the exception and go on with the Base36 decode function for sequence that doesn't contain a value, now you nicely have 2 errors in your log which are caused by one reason

Comment: I made some changes. Does it look okay now?

Comment: @Melissa No. In your first code block, if the call to `_sequenceRepository.Get` fails, then the attempt to access the property `sequence.Value` will throw a null reference exception. You should abandon the attempt after the first error.

Comment: @Melissa As stated by Ergwun your code is still not ok. The AddOrUpdate function is dependant on the results of the Get function. If the Get function fails you should set the errors and return. Trying to execute AddOrUpdate anyway is **wrong**.

Comment: Looking better, but it would be even better if you used Exceptions as they were meant to: i.e. the Exception itself should carry information about the error.

Comment: @NeXuS - Is there a way that I can check the error message from the exception?

Comment: @Melissa You can get the message embedded in an exception by using the ToString() method or accessing the Message property. You can also obtain information regarding the stack at the moment the Exception was generated by accessing the StackTrace property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sacrificing exact exception stack traces on the altar of error message readability (not to mention *code readability*).

**Consider your audience**: a developer. A developer should be able to read an exception stack trace, which is much more valuable debugging information than a short error message.

Hence my suggestion is to only put in **one** exception handler for logging somewhere higher up the hierarchy. If you have to have one in your current method, at least capture the full exception stack trace.

Also - does it really make sense to continue after the first exception? If retrieving the sequence fails, using its value in the next try block won't fair any better. It does not make sense having multiple try/catch blocks here, unless you know exactly how to solve the problem in each catch handler so you can continue.

Update:

Now that you have a single try/catch block code readability is improved. It still looks very odd that you are basically returning a list of errors to the caller - the error case should be exceptional, so it should not bleed into the business logic of your method, instead I would just let the exception go up the stack until you can truly handle the problem (or just log it and exit the app).

Answer (score 2):

Your code should ideally look something like this (I will be inventing class names here and there): i.e. you should have one try block and multiple handlers which depend on the type of exception raised.

The reason why you should have only one try block is that, as pointed out by others, the two queries are related, and you should not perform the update if the select has gone wrong.

```
public IDictionary<string, string> GetNextBase36(string partitionKey, string rowKey, ref string seq)
{
    Sequence sequence;
    try {
        sequence = _sequenceRepository.Get(u => u.PartitionKey == partitionKey & u.RowKey == rowKey);
        sequence.Value = Base36.Encode(Base36.Decode(sequence.Value) + 1);
        _sequenceRepository.AddOrUpdate(sequence);
        seq = sequence.Value;
    } catch( SelectException e )  {
        _errors.Add("", "Database error:  Get sequence failed");
    } catch( UpdateException e )  {
        _errors.Add("", "Database error: Updating sequence failed");
    } catch {
        _errors.Add("", "Database error: Something really bad happened!");
    }

    return _errors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you fail to get the item from the database, does it make sense that you should attempt to update it?  Wrap the whole thing in a single `try { ... } catch ()` block *if* you intend to handle/translate exceptions at *that* point in your code.